# Problem with openfeint 2.12.2 - integration issue

Tags: iphone, openfeint

I am trying to integrate OpenFeint 2.12.2 into my game, everything compiles and links, but while runtime it crashes in function [OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:(...)], at line:
+[OpenFeint sharedInstance]: unrecognized selector sent to class

I am using xcode 3.2.5 and framework version of OF; tried to clean, rebuild, RECOMPILE whole thing, nothing works. I am testing it on iPad 4.2, iPhone 4.1 and simulator.

Any ideas? 
Cheers!

Comment: I'm also stuck..I can't get it working, any solution?? I already try some [tutorials](http://pocketworx.com/?p=80) , [and this](http://hacker-pro.com/forum/index.php?topic=1658.0)  and read the documentation.. but i couldn't get it.
could you give a hand?? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using openfeint 2.12.5 and done necessary linker setting.It runs fine in simulator but crashes on device.I am stuck in this.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation that comes with OpenFeint - there are necessary linker settings that you have to add to make sure the linker doesn't strip out Objective-C necessary Objective-C routines. From the [documentation](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/readme-for-openfeint-ios-sdk-2-12-2/):

> In (your project)->Build Settings->Linking, add the value `-all_load` to Other Linker Flags. If you make the changes at the PROJECT level, make sure your settings aren’t overridden at the TARGET level: Anything done at the TARGET level takes precedence.

and:

> Add the value `-ObjC` to all configurations under Linking->Other Linker Flags

There's a lot more in there, so please be sure to read up!

Also: the latest version is 2.12.2 as far as I can tell: what's the motivation behind linking in an older version (2.1.12)? The older version may be the source of some of your troubles as well.

Comment: `-all_load` or `-ObjC` to Linking->Other Linker Flags? Your answer seems to have some redundancy in it.